# Best/MostEfficient way to check if at least one input is entered by user

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to take in multiple parameters from a function and im am checking if at least one of the parameters are not null or empty.

right now i am doing something like this.

```
void foo(String a, String b, String c, String d, ... other strings){

//make sure at least one of the inputs are not null.
if(a!=null || b!=null || c!=null || d!=null ... more strings){
  //do something with the string
}

}
```

so an input can be `foo(null, null, null, "hey");`
but it cannot be `foo(null, null, null, null);`

What my question is is there a better way to do this, rather than keep adding to the if statement.  Im blanking out right now.... Thanks

Comment: How many arguments do you really have for that function?  That itself can be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use varags

```
   public static boolean atLeastOneEmpty(String firstString, String... strings){
      if(firstString == null || firstString.isEmpty())
         return true;

      for(String str : strings){
         if(str == null || str.isEmpty())
            return true;
      }
      return false;

    }
```

Returns true if at least one string is empty

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! I would modify it to take `public static boolean atLeastOneEmpty(String str, String... strings)` . Makes it more readable and easy to understand that at least one argument is needed.

Comment: I think he needs the opposite function, atLeastOneNonEmpty, but you can edit this answer for that.

Comment: @Kathy You are probably right, but if the OP understands what I am doing then he should be able to inverse it easily.

Comment: ahh i seee now.. thanks! ill just reverse that. its much neater

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late, but from [Apache Commons Lange 3.11](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) you can use the method [`ObjectUtils.anyNotNull()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#anyNotNull-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: Was hoping this would work for me but it doesn't check for empty as well as Null, so unfortunately it doesn't answer OP's question